# Can anyone tell me about the pin configuration of 16 pin I2C module?

Tags: i2c

I am using I2C with 4*4 keypad. But i cannot find the pinout of I2C. Can anyone help me with this?
The link for I2C image is:-

https://www.14core.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/I2C-LCD-Module-Board-Arduino-AVR-PIC.jpg

I want to know the pinout of these 16 pins of I2C. Please help me with this!!

Comment: Why did you include some photo, and not the actual reference, datasheet or anything? How am I going to find this chip using an image?

Comment: I told in the question that it is an I2C module

Comment: I think you should read the question again

Comment: [with one](https://botland.com.pl/en/search?controller=search&orderby=position&orderway=desc&search_query=i2c+module&submit_search=)? The one with HD44780 interface? [such one](https://elty.pl/pl/p/Konwerter-I2C-LCD/885?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIgr33ntCk4QIVVqWaCh2gkA5SEAQYAiABEgLijPD_BwE)? It's a HD44780 interface not 4*4 keypad. It has a simple PCF8574T . Or it doesn't, because you didn't tell what you have, just a simple image. What am I going to do with this image? Do you expect others to read the name of the IC from the image and somehow magically know how it's connected?

Comment: you just didn't understood what i am trying to ask

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a Tutorial](https://robot-electronics.co.uk/i2c-tutorial) that might help in explaining how I2C works.

From the board you have linked to, on the right there is an SDA and SCL lines which are the two data lines for generating an I2C connection.

Comment: I just want to know about the pin configuration of I2C apart from from those 4 pins (GND,VCC,SDA,SCL). so that i can do some connections with that. without knowing the pinout , how could i connect it to something? Also i know, the working of I2C, but the problem lies only in the pinout

Answer (score 1):

These 16 pin are the standard [hd44780](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf) connection with 4 pins left free. The IC in the picture is [PCF8574T](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCF8574_PCF8574A.pdf) the SO16 package version.

Only en, rw, rs, D4, D5, D6, D7 of hd44780 are connected, so it's enough to use 4 pin interface for HD44780. The pinout of the 16 pin is standard hd44780, you can even find it on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitachi_HD44780_LCD_controller). The first pin on the image you posted is on the right side, where is the additional white line between the pins.

As I couldn't find the exact schematics of the device, reverse engineering it shouldn't be very hard using a simple program and a voltage meter. Or you can use [this site](https://tronixstuff.com/2014/09/24/tutorial-serial-pcf8574-backpacks-hd44780-compatible-lcd-modules-arduino/) to know the configuration for `LiquidCrystal_I2C  lcd(0x27,2,1,0,4,5,6,7);` class. I would expect the numbers `2,1,0,4,5,6,7` to be the pins on PCF8574T, so one could create a table:

```
HD44780 signal - pin number on PCF8574T
en - 2
rw - 1
rs - 0
and so on...
```

Comment: See!! Can you tell me how do i connect I2C with 4*4 keypad?

Comment: No, no, I cannot.